# STM32F4 configuring exti port interrupt at one function

Tags: c, interrupt, stm32

I configured `gpio` and `exti` handler configurations for 8 pins `(PD8,PD9...PD15)` each has separate configuration functions and it's working well. Can i do the configurations at just one function? Some lines uses same irq channel, is that a problem? I want to use it like this (syntax is not important, you can just say its possible)

```
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_8 | GPIO_Pin_9 | GPIO_Pin_10 | GPIO_Pin_11 |
                                 GPIO_Pin_12 | GPIO_Pin_13 | GPIO_Pin_14 | GPIO_Pin_15);    

  GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  SYSCFG_EXTILineConfig(EXTI_PortSourceGPIOD,EXTI_PinSource8 | EXTI_PinSource9| 
                                              EXTI_PinSource10| EXTI_PinSource11| 
                                               EXTI_PinSource12| EXTI_PinSource13| 
                                                 EXTI_PinSource14| EXTI_PinSource15);

  /* Configure EXTI Line0 */
  EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Line = EXTI_Line15;
  EXTI_InitStructure.EXTI_Mode = EXTI_Mode_Interrupt;
  EXTI_Init(&EXTI_InitStructure);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* initialise all your GPIO pins in one line, that's safe. You *cannot* do all your calls to `SYSCFG_EXTILineConfig` in one line, that's not allowed. The reason is that the `EXTI_PinSourceN` values are numeric constants and not bitmasks. See `stm32f4xx_syscfg.h` for reference.